# Cherenkov Radiation: Does it need to be faster than light in the certain medium?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, refraction, faster-than-light, shock-waves, cherenkov-radiation

I understand that when a charged particle moves through a medium and excites the atoms nearby, it produces a blue light when the atoms 'de-excite"
However, I don't understand why it has to be faster than light in the medium. Shouldn't the charged particle still excite nearby atoms when passing by?

Comment: this link may help http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/einvel.html#c3

Answer (score 3):

> However, I don't understand why it has to be faster than light in the medium. Shouldn't the charged particle still excite nearby atoms when passing by?

If you read [the link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/einvel.html#c3) you will see that the classical modeling of Cerenkov light does not involve the quantum mechanical domain of the medium consisting of atoms with excited states. It is modeled with the [index of refraction](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/refr.html#c2) $n=c/v$ where $v$ is the velocity, and the blue light is well modeled.

If you are talking on the atomic model, of course a charged particle can interact with atoms and change the energy levels of the electrons or the bonding of molecules , but there will be a spectrum produced, when that happens, and the probability of interaction is small,on direct hits.

Here is the atomic/molecules model

> [Cherenkov photon emission](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/cherenkov-radiation) is the result of local polarization along the path of travel of the charged particle with the emission of electromagnetic radiation when the polarized molecules return to their original states (Gruhn and Ogle, 1980). This has been described by Marshall (1952) as the electromagnetic “shock” wave that is analogous to the acoustical shock wave or sonic boom created by supersonic aircraft.

Comment: Really nice answer. "but there will be a spectrum produced, when that happens", can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei electrons changing atomic energy levels will give spectral lines  see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/atspect.html

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei if you want some more concrete examples of spectra, you can google "EELS spectrum" and see many pictures of spectra. (EELS is an abbreviation for "electron energy loss spectroscopy). EELS is similar to X-ray spectroscopy except instead of using probe X-rays to excite atomic electrons, it uses probe electrons excite the atomic electrons.

Comment: I have this question about accelerating charges https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/672714/bomb-attached-to-accelerating-charge-as-viewed-from-a-co-moving-frame please take a look at it.